# DateTime filtering in Telerik RadGrid

Tags: filter, telerik, radgrid, telerik-grid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Telerik Grid Filter not working on Date column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305083/telerik-grid-filter-not-working-on-date-column)

I have a radgrid which has a date time column. I would like to display both the date and the time in the column, which is no problem. The problem is I would also like to allow the user to filter the column based on the date. This doesn't work. The selected date never matches anything because of the time part of the datetime.

Is there any way to allow the filter to only look at the date part of the date, not the datetime combined, while still displaying the time?

Comment: [Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-filtering-for-griddatetimecolumn-with-dataformatstring.html) is a powerful tool....