# Telerik Grid Filter not working on Date column

Tags: grid, telerik

I have a Telerik Grid with one of the column having Date Time values, but the filter on that field is not working as the filter only accepts date by default.
Is there any way we can have the time included in the telerik grid filter?

Here is my code:

Html.Telerik().Grid()

```
        .Name("FilesGrid")
        .Sortable(sorting => sorting.OrderBy(sortOrder => sortOrder.Add(o => o.COL1)))
        .Pageable(paging =>
            paging.PageSize(10)
                    .Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric)
                    .Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom)
        ).Filterable()
        .Groupable()
        .Selectable()
        .Resizable(c => c.Columns(true))
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.
            Ajax()
                .Select("_Grid", "Files")
                .Update("_ClientUpdate", "Todos")
                .Insert("_ClientInsert", "Todos")
                .Delete("Delete", "Files"))
                        .EnableCustomBinding(true)  
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.col1);
            columns.Bound(c => c.col2);
            columns.Bound(c => c.col3);
            columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedAt);  -------- this column is datetime but filter only has date calendar , hence the filter wont work
        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBound("onGridDataBound"))
%>
```

Comment: You're going to have to overwrite the filter expression, Telerik provides an example in their documentation of exactly what you're looking for: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-filtering-for-griddatetimecolumn-with-dataformatstring.html

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but I will put a solution for those people search for it

I have customized this solution, it works with all scenarios and you can use it also if you have more than one column have a date time filter  use this function in the need data source event
first put this function in your code

```
  Protected Sub manageDateFilter(ByVal columnName As String, ByVal source As Object, ByVal filter As String, ByVal columnindex As Integer)


        Select Case DirectCast(DirectCast(source, Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid).Columns.Item(columnindex), Telerik.Web.UI.GridDateTimeColumn).CurrentFilterFunction
            Case GridKnownFunction.EqualTo
                Dim date1 As datetime = convert.todatetime(DirectCast(DirectCast(source, Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid).Columns.Item(columnindex), Telerik.Web.UI.GridDateTimeColumn).CurrentFilterValue)


                grdReport.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = filter.replace("([" + columnName + "] = " + filter.substring(filter.indexof(columnName) + (columnName.length + 4)).trim().substring(0, filter.substring(filter.indexof(columnName) + (columnName.length + 4)).indexof("M") + 2) + ")".trim(), "([" + columnName + "] >= '" + date1.tostring() + "') AND ([" + columnName + "] < '" + date1.adddays(1).tostring() + "')")

            Case GridKnownFunction.NotEqualTo
                Dim date1 As datetime = convert.todatetime(DirectCast(DirectCast(source, Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid).Columns.Item(columnindex), Telerik.Web.UI.GridDateTimeColumn).CurrentFilterValue)


                grdReport.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = filter.replace("([" + columnName + "] <> " + filter.substring(filter.indexof(columnName) + (columnName.length + 4)).trim().substring(0, filter.substring(filter.indexof(columnName) + (columnName.length + 5)).indexof("M") + 2) + ")".trim(), "(([" + columnName + "] < '" + date1.tostring() + "') OR ([" + columnName + "] >= '" + date1.adddays(1).tostring() + "'))")

            Case GridKnownFunction.GreaterThanOrEqualTo
                Dim date1 As datetime = convert.todatetime(DirectCast(DirectCast(source, Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid).Columns.Item(columnindex), Telerik.Web.UI.GridDateTimeColumn).CurrentFilterValue)


                grdReport.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = filter.replace("([" + columnName + "] >= " + filter.substring(filter.indexof(columnName) + (columnName.length + 4)).trim().substring(0, filter.substring(filter.indexof(columnName) + (columnName.length + 4)).indexof("M") + 2) + ")".trim(), "([" + columnName + "] >= '" + date1.tostring() + "')")

            Case GridKnownFunction.LessThanOrEqualTo
                Dim date1 As datetime = convert.todatetime(DirectCast(DirectCast(source, Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid).Columns.Item(columnindex), Telerik.Web.UI.GridDateTimeColumn).CurrentFilterValue)


                grdReport.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = filter.replace("([" + columnName + "] <= " + filter.substring(filter.indexof(columnName) + (columnName.length + 4)).trim().substring(0, filter.substring(filter.indexof(columnName) + (columnName.length + 5)).indexof("M") + 2) + ")".trim(), "([" + columnName + "] <= '" + date1.adddays(1).tostring() + "') ")

            Case GridKnownFunction.GreaterThan
                Dim date1 As datetime = convert.todatetime(DirectCast(DirectCast(source, Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid).Columns.Item(columnindex), Telerik.Web.UI.GridDateTimeColumn).CurrentFilterValue)


                grdReport.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = filter.replace("([" + columnName + "] > " + filter.substring(filter.indexof(columnName) + (columnName.length + 4)).trim().substring(0, filter.substring(filter.indexof(columnName) + (columnName.length + 4)).indexof("M") + 2) + ")".trim(), "([" + columnName + "] >= '" + date1.adddays(1).tostring() + "') ")

        End Select
```

and then you call it from the need data source event for the grid like this

```
Dim filter As String = grdReport.MasterTableView.FilterExpression
            If (filter.contains("LAST_UPD_DATE")) Then
                manageDateFilter("LAST_UPD_DATE", source, filter, 6)
            End If
```

and for multi date column you can use it like this

```
Dim filter As String = ReportGrid.MasterTableView.FilterExpression
            If (filter.contains("START_DATE")) Then
                manageDateFilter("START_DATE", source, filter, 5)
            End If
            filter = ReportGrid.MasterTableView.FilterExpression
            If (filter.contains("END_DATE")) Then
                manageDateFilter("END_DATE", source, filter, 6)
            End If
```

enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void ItemsRadGrid_ItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.FilterCommandName)
        {
            try
            {
                FillItemsGrid();
                FilterByDate(ItemsRadGrid, e);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ExceptionLogClass.InsertError(ex);
            }

        }

    }

public static void FilterByDate(RadGrid grid, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Pair filterPair = e.CommandArgument as Pair;
        string columnName = Convert.ToString(filterPair.Second);
        if (filterPair.First.ToString() == "NoFilter")
        { }
        else
        {
            if (grid.Columns.FindByDataField(columnName).DataType.Name == "DateTime")
            {
                try
                {
                    TextBox FilterColumnField = ((TextBox)((GridFilteringItem)e.Item)[columnName].Controls[0]);
                    string oldDate = FilterColumnField.Text;
                    FilterColumnField.Text = DateTime.ParseExact(FilterColumnField.Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy 12:00:00 tt");
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    e.Canceled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```